# How to Place $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-p^2} dp$ in the form of the error function?

Tags: error-function

The error function is definted as $erf(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^x e^{-p^2} dp$. I have the function $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-p^2}dp$. I can switch the bounds of the integral, then I would have $-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{-\infty} e^{-p^2} dp$. However, if I switch the signs of the limits then I have a different expression that I am taking the integral of and hence I don't have the error function anymore. I do believe the answer is one, just like $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-p^2} dp = 1$. This is for a partial differential equations class.

Side note: This should probably belong in META, but how do we search very specific questions on this website? Sometimes I post a question and there is a link that someone posts that goes to a question very similar to mine (which I can use to solve the problem). But whenever I search myself I can never find anything. Not sure if it has to be typed in LaTeX.

Comment: Try a substitution  $u=-p$.

Comment: $e^{-p^2}$ is an even function of $p$, so it does not matter if you integrate it from $-\infty$ to $0$ or from $0$ to $\infty$, the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-p^2}dp=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{-\infty}e^{-p^2}dp=-\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}\text{erf}(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\text{erf}(x)$$

The last step is because $\text{erf}(x)$ is an odd function. Credit to @march's comment for helping me spot that.

I also believe that the answer is $1$.

As for searching for specific questions, I would recommend checking out this [thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/how-do-you-search-for-specific-questions/24882). Personally when I search for questions, I avoid searching using any math expressions instead search for key words that might be related in both Google and Stack Exchange. In this case, I would have tried googling "alternate forms of the error function" or something like that.

Comment: Ah, pretty nice. Appreciate it and thanks @march.